# Insert follow by delete does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server when I execute these two commands together

```
    INSERT INTO TABLEB SELECT * FROM TABLEC WHERE TABLEC.COLUMNC = 'ABC'
    DELETE TABLEC where TABLEC.columnC = 'ABC'
```

I only get the delete result. Insert did return a message saying x row affected but the content in the table remains empty.

Actual code

```
    INSERT INTO STORECODE_BK SELECT * FROM STORE WHERE STOREID = '334'
    DELETE STORE where STOREID = '334'
```

Comment: What if you execute `INSERT INTO TABLEB` then `SELECT FROM TABLEB` then `DELETE TABLEF` then `SELECT FROM TABLEB` again? What's the result?

Comment: I can't because if I delete from tableC no value can be added to TableB

Comment: Are you setting the columns values? Can you post your real code?

Comment: do u have any foreign key referencing between two table?

Comment: @user1761160: I mean, append a `SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE TABLEC.COLUMNC = 'ABC'` after each command, to monitor `TABLEB`'s state after each step.

Comment: As a diagnostic, try doing `SELECT * FROM TABLEC WHERE TABLEC.COLUMNC = 'ABC'` first. Maybe there are simply no rows that match the criteria sometimes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: He already said he got a _x rows affected_ response, so...

Comment: No relationship between the 2 table. Even if constrain exist, there shall have a message saying describing the constrain

Comment: may be there on delete cascade constraint

Comment: in Oracle I will use commit in between. but in MS SQL any similar solution?

Comment: @Amit Singh no such constrain

Comment: @John, there is row return. As mention, Insert no content, but it managed to delete the record

Comment: @user1761160: Not necessarily. If a `STORECODE_BK` FK points to `STORE` and has a `ON DELETE CASCADE` attribute, then deleting relevant PKs from `STORE` will delete corresponding rows from `STORECODE_BK` "silently".

Comment: @geomagas YES!!!! You got it right!!!

Comment: Not just me. See @AmitSingh's comment above (also he was the first to "hint" us all towards there!)

Comment: Thanks to AmitSigh too!

Answer (score 1):

geomagas Had gotten the solution
Is due to the ON DELETE CASCADE attribute which delete the relevant PK
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
INSERT INTO STORECODE_BK SELECT * FROM STORE WHERE STOREID = '334'
GO
DELETE FROM STORE where STOREID = '334'
GO
```

Comment: P.S. if this is going to be an executed stored procedure, you will want to specifically select the columns rather than using *, as that relies on both tables having the same columns in the same order and is dangerous.

Comment: Well if it is the GO's will have to come out. They are directives for the Query tool, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Select into a temporary table.

Then use that to insert into TableB and maybe delete from Table C

Then select from the temporary table.

Got to say all the hoops you are having to jump through indicates a less than great design.